# How to make start and end slope points zero in spline?

Tags: matlab

This is my MATLAB code:

```
a = [-1, 0, 1, 2];
b = [1, 0, -1, 1];
ss = spline(a, b, 1.5)
```

I want MATLAB to calculate the answer when `s0=s3=0`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Input Arguments" section of the [`spline` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html). It says that if the vector `b` has exactly two more elements than the vector `a`, then the first and last values of `b` are used to specify slope values at the ends.

Since you require zero slopes at the two ends, you should do:

```
a = [-1, 0, 1, 2];
b = [0, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0]; %first and last values specify end slopes
ss = spline(a, b, 1.5)
```

Comment: Thanks.If we don't specify custom slopes what is a default slopes in matlab?

Comment: If we don't specify end slopes, the documentation says that "not-a-knot" end conditions are used. "Not-a-knot" conditions only require that the third derivative of the spline is continuous at the end-points, so the end slopes (i.e. first derivatives) are not constrained. There's no default slope that's enforced. You can read more about spline end conditions [here](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~turkel/notes/numeng/spline_note.pdf).